# Magnolia CMS 5.5.5 deny access to some dam-Files

Tags: security, pdf, content-management-system, magnolia, dam

I got users and roles. Access to certain parts of the the content is denied in the ftls but I got the following problem:

I want prevent users from sharing pdf links.
These are formed like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/dam/jcr:c383c3c-a27a-4baf-856f-265baaf02142/mozillasecure.pdf
```

In the dam workspace I have two folders `pdf` and `pdfsecure` I want the pdfs in the `pdf` to be downloadable for all roles and the ones in the `pdfsecure` folder to be denied for ie. anonymous role..

How can I accomplish that?

Note: I thought about extending the DamURI2RepositoryMapping.java but I couldnt see it through, please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a trick question? :)

Simply set content permission for anonymous role to "deny" on `pdfsecure` and subnodes via security app. Make sure to set it directly on public instance (author and public have different anonymous role configuration so you don't want to activate that).

Setting permission on the content level, in difference from setting it at URI level, makes sure content is not accessible via any URI.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: No it was actually not. Now I see it works :) I got a further going question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035079/magnolia-cms-5-5-5-choose-from-roles) please help Jan :)