# Magnolia CMS 5.5.5 Choose from roles

Tags: security, content-management-system, jcr, magnolia

I am looking for a possibility to choose certain roles in a Page property Dialog. Some parts of the page should be only viewable to certain roles.

What I got is

```
- name: allowedRoles
  class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
  label: Select Roles
  field:
    name: roleLinkField
    class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
    targetWorkspace: userroles
    appName: security
    identifierToPathConverter:
      class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.converter.BaseIdentifierToPathConverter
```

This lets me only choose user not userroles.. What do I need to do to choose from the subapp of "security" called "roles"?

Comment: Hmm. I'd expect that to work as is. Can't check the code right now. As workaround you can create custom app (just copy security app really) and move roles subapp there as first workbench/subapp and refer to that one. See if that gets you going.

Comment: Thats an idea but i'd rather not go that way.. please let me know if you see another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this took a while to figure out, but turns out relatively simple in the end:

- define `chooseDialog` in the app from which you want to choose from different subapp explicitly (in your case in `security-app`)
- in the `chooseDialog`, define workbench field pointing to workbench in subapp of interest (roles in your case). Class definition for the field must be specified here explicitly.
- also in `chooseDialog`, define `contentConnector` pointing to connector of interest (in roles subapp in your case)
- in the dialog where you are adding the link field, in the definition of the link field, set `appName` to the app (`security` in your case) and set `targetWorkspace` to the workspace of the connector you linked from `chooseDialog` in the step above (`userroles` in your case).

All should work then. Limitation is that you can have only one such choose dialog definition per app so you have to choose from which subapp you want to link items from.

Example of configuration for what you want: https://gist.github.com/rah003/29910e92067effaebed9156d6bdc293a

[image]

HTH,
Jan